# Password reset during sign fails in a desktop app

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C authentication in native app to web API service scenario. Communication with AD is done with **Microsoft.Identity.Client** package (1.0.304142201-alpha), as recommended in [current Azure docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-native-dotnet/).

When I try to use self-service password reset during sign-in, after pressing button Next on the first page (with login and captcha image), I get **MsalException** with **non_https_redirect_failed** error.

This feature works fine for the same AD B2C tenant in a web app with **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** package (2.28.1) and in a desktop app with previously recommended **Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** (4.0.209160138-alpha)

Comment: In MSAL, we don't allow redirecting to non-https urls. What is your redirect URI? this could be a bug.

Comment: I do not pass redirect URI explicitly. However, the Microsoft.Identity.Client assembly passes **urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob** under the hood (at least it should) as for any native app. The same URI is specified as redirect URI for corresponding app in AD B2C settings ("Yes" for Native client).

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: Several months have passed, any new info from MSFT?
The package had no updates since then, the issue remains.


Does anyone else experience this issue? Maybe there is something specific in configuration of my AD or code using the library?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently updated my code to Microsoft.Identity.Client v1.1.2-preview0008. Password reset works with that version.